# Share a component instance between different Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

HI,

I just want to share a component from one Form to others...

I have a component which manage an action List. I would like to implement action in one class and affect them on multiple forms.

The simple way is to do that :

```
public class Form1 : Form
```

=> contains the component :

```
public class ActionList : System.ComponentModel.Component, IExtenderProvider
```

this componend is use AT DESIGN TIME to set Actions

```
public class Form2 : Form1
```

=> Form2 see the component thought Form1, and i can add value to the component (Modifier = public), but of course Form1 don't see added action on form2 (inheritence basic property)

```
public class Form3 : Form1
```

**that could work, but i've both classic Form , and devexpress RibbonForm**

`RibbonForm` inherits `XtraForm` inherits `Form`.

Whats the best way to do that ? (the action list component contains Designer Editor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you cannot save your component in the separate from Forms classes in other class
for example

```
public class MyClassWithComponent
{
    // put you code from component
}
```

and you can use this class everywhere

Comment: By Component i mean ... System.ComponentModel.Component

Comment: You also can put this component in the separate class

Comment: thats already done, but that does not resolve inheritance problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should investigate moving the common component to a [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx) to referencing it from both forms.

Comment: nope "component which manage an action List" is not a list<action>, its a graphic designer component that manage list of actions during design time

Comment: that doesn't work neither, i can't access to a the component designer when i put the control in a form ...